# gltf material override stops animation mixer

Tags: aframe, webvr, gltf

I'm very stuck with an issue with a gltf model. If I try to override the gltf's material, the animation stops. I think it has something to do with the update function of the override and the tick function of the animation mixer colliding somehow, but I haven't managed to solve it on my own.

I hope someone can point me to the direction of why this is happening.
Here's a live example: http://motiondolphins.com/app_onlyFefo/index.html

Immense thanks in advance. Here's the code itself. The commented section is the override of the material. If I uncomment it, the new material loads but the animation stops:

```
        AFRAME.registerComponent("fefo", {
            init: function() {

                var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'models/static.png' );
                texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                texture.repeat.set( 20, 20 );


                this.material  = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
                    bumpMap:texture,
                    bumpScale:0.03,

                    color : 0xffffff
            });

            this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => this.update());


            var el = this.el;
            setTimeout(()=>{
                var model = el.getObject3D('mesh')       
                this.mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model);
                var clips = model.animations || (model.geometry || {}).animations || 
                [];
                console.log(this.mixer)
                console.log(el)
                console.log(clips[0])
                const action = this.mixer.clipAction(clips[0], model);
                action.setDuration(10).setLoop(THREE.LoopRepeat).play();
                console.log(action)
            }, 3000)
            },

            /////////////////HERE I TRY TO OVERRIDE THE MATERIAL, BUT IF I DO, ANIMATION STOPS

            update: function () {

            //      object = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');

            //     if (!object) return;
            //     object.traverse((node) => {

            //     if (node.isMesh) node.material = this.material;
            // }); 

        },
            tick: function (t, dt) {

                if (this.mixer && !isNaN(dt)) this.mixer.update(dt / 1000);

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to keep in mind that a Material in three.js actually represents a [WebGL shader program](https://thebookofshaders.com/01/), not just the visual "look" of an object. MeshToonMaterial extends [MeshPhongMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/MeshPhongMaterial), and inherits several properties related to animation which need to be preserved in order for animation to work:

```
newMaterial.skinning = oldMaterial.skinning;
newMaterial.morphTargets = oldMaterial.morphTargets;
newMaterial.morphNormals = oldMaterial.morphNormals;
```

In this case I think it's just the `.skinning` property that is important, because the model uses a skeleton.

Comment: Thank you so much for your informative answer Don.
Indeed, just adding 

this.material.skinning = true;

in the update function solved this problem